# Why doesn't function get called on first page load, only after refreshing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I've searched, but I could not find the solution to this problem. For some reason function doesn't get called when page loads the first time, only after refreshing the page it gets called. Examples:

```
function init() {

    alert("hello");
}
```

Either calling the function with following method:

```
$(window).load(function () {

    init();

});
```

Or inside a body tag:

```
<body onLoad="init()">
```

Also, this problem doesn't occur when I open page directly, only when I'm being linked to the page from another page.

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: @Sam that wouldn't explain why it _does_ execute after a refresh.

Comment: No I'm not getting any errors.

Comment: @Stybos are you able to reproduce that behaviour?

Comment: `only when I'm being linked to the page from another page.` what do you mean by this? With which page are you linking your page to

Comment: This can only mean one thing, the page probably hasn't finished loading.

Comment: @11684 Do you not think it is prudent to check anyway?

Comment: @Corneliu that doesn't matter because the OP doesn't interact with the DOM!

Comment: Yeah, you're right...  @Sam

Comment: @Stybos - Use Fiddler to check for pending requests

Comment: Any errors in console? For sure, `<body onload="">` is case sensitive.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp Really? Let me try that!

Comment: @Corneliu I will check that later, I'm not familiar with Fiddler.

Comment: This problem still hasn't been solved.

Comment: There's nothing in the code you have shown that would cause the behavior. You'll have to show a live example of a page that shows the problem.

Comment: I think I reproduced it. It is due to the fact that `$(document).ready()` never fires in my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YZ8Hw/

Comment: This update is interesting too: http://jsfiddle.net/YZ8Hw/1/

Comment: Here's an example: http://www.solidfiles.com/d/486142b480/

Comment: Works only in Mozilla for some reason... another problem is here, I can't go back to previous page by clicking browser's 'back' button.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp no its not, even `onLOad` works fine, element attributes are not case sensitive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, mobile options must be set before loading jquery.mobile.

```
<script language=javascript>
    $(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
        $.mobile.ajaxLinksEnabled = false;
        $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
    });
</script>   
<script src="scripts/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something in the lines of:

```
function init() {
    alert('Hello!');
}

window.onload(function() {
    init();
}
```

Comment: @Juhana I agree with you, although I want to add that it _might_ be a jQuery bug, in which case this might differ from the OP's code. (But I don't think it is a jQuery bug.)